# How can I combine two database records to one and sum a quantity?

Tags: php, sql

How can I make the duplicate record to be RECORDED AS ONE and the QUANTITY will get the total as 3 based on the picture below

[image: screenshot]

This is the code:

```
$id=$_GET['invoice'];
include('connect.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales_order WHERE invoice= :userid");
$result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
$result->execute();

for ($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
```

Comment: You can adapt your SQL query to include elements like `SELECT SUM(quantity)` and `GROUP BY product code`

Comment: thank you sir / it works but I got this error == Undefined index: product in C:\xampp\htdocs\sales\pages\cashier\sales.php on line 251 same as the other column

Comment: Could you show us line 251

Comment: sir can I ask another question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` in your query.

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity), `Product Code`, 
`Brand Name`, `Description Name`, `Price`, `Discount`, `VAT`, `Ammount`, 
`Total Amount`
FROM sales_order WHERE invoice=:userid 
GROUP BY `Product Code`, `Brand Name`, `Description Name`
```

You can also do the following:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Quantity)
FROM sales_order WHERE invoice=:userid
GROUP BY `Product Code`, `Brand Name`, `Description Name`
```

Comment: thank you sir / it works but I got this error == Undefined index: product in C:\xampp\htdocs\sales\pages\cashier\sales.php on line 251 same as the other column

Comment: Can you show line 251? Cause product is never asked in this whole question so it should not even be in relation to this

Comment: <td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>

Comment: the 'product' itself sir was the representation for the product code

Comment: I got this sir =  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM sales_order WHERE invoice='RS-6333523'

Comment: (continuation) == GROUP BY `product`' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sales\pages\cashier\sales.php:246 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sales\pages\cashier\sales.php(246): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sales\pages\cashier\sales.php on line 246

Comment: @MarkDonadillo I was not ready with updating my answer, you should try the updated..

Comment: wow it works sir!  but there still a problem the appeared number of QUANTITY still show "1" it does not adding the other added number of quantity

Comment: based on the picture above / it should show 3 (total number of quantity)

Comment: @MarkDonadillo try updated, I made a fiddle and i get the desired output,  I am certain your where statement is restricting you from getting desired output

Comment: where can I see the fiddle sir? :)

Comment: oh well I guess it's enough haha ty sir I'll gonna be like you too next year or less lol :) :P